# How can I "emulate" a sealed lead acid battery using capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, lead-acid

I have an appliance that requires a sealed lead acid battery as AC backup, but I do NOT need backup power for the appliance since the supply to the device is already under UPS backup.

The device somehow tests the battery by removing the 13.8V charging voltage, and then measures voltage and other things on battery for half a second. It then complains of a battery error. It continues to do this test each second second.

What I now want to do, is to replace the missing battery with a few capacitors that will "emulate" a lead acid battery. Since the test is only run for like half a second, the capacitor only needs to be able to supply energy for a second or so.

I tried with paralleling 4 capacitors so it become 2200uF in total, and then connecting to the device as a battery, but still the device does not recongnize the "battery".

What do I need to do to "fool" the device that a battery is present? I checked around about internal resistance, and it suggest a few mOhm as internal resistance, but I guess that a lower internal resistance is "better" right?

I also measured with a voltmeter over the capacitors and they DO get charged correctly by the charging current, to the 13.8V so the device should be able to detect the voltage, but somehow it doesn't.

Checking in the menu, it still says "Unknown" on battery voltage and battery current.

Any ideas how a device, which removes charging power each second second, tests a sealed lead acid battery?

Comment: What test equipment do you have? It may want the voltage to be within a range. It may be too high with only a cap. You may need to add a zener diode. But, you will probably need a series resistor also.

Answer (score 2):

We can emulate a battery with a cheaper battery.

For example, 10x NiMH AA in series should be able to do a decent impersonation of a 12V lead acid battery. A bit higher internal resistance, but that could be OK.

A cheaper/smaller solution may be possible, but that requires knowing how the device tests its battery. It's probably measuring voltage while drawing some current, but how much and for how long is another question that requires some disassembly and probing.

If it tests the battery under load by switching a resistor with a MOSFET to draw current, removing the resistor may be a way to cheat.